# Salting out constant in activity coefficient

Tags: physical-chemistry, experimental-chemistry

Based on [this Wikipedia page for activity coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Activity_coefficient#Theoretical_calculation_of_activity_coefficients), I know that the activity coefficient for a nonelectrolyte can be determined using a "salting-out" model with the following equation:

$$\begin{aligned}\log_{10}(\gamma_0) &= bI\\
\gamma_0 &= \text{activity coefficient}\\
b &= \text{empirical constant}\\
I &= \text{ionic strength}
\end{aligned}$$

This equation and the accompanying wiki leaves three related questions about its use:

1. How would I determine that empirical constant $b$?
2. How do I interpret the ionic strength of a nonelectrolyte solution?
3. What does this equation have anything to do with "salting out" - reducing the solubility of nonelectrolytes in aqueous solution by increasing the ionic strength?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salting_out

Comment: @ringo - your link does not include an equation for determining activity coefficients based on the "salting-out" model. The [wikipedia page for activity coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Activity_coefficient) does give the formula, but does not provide an explanation of how to determine the empirical constant (or honestly how the formula is related to salting out).